# UDP in a client/server application

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, client-server

For my Network Engineering 2 class I have to program a packet transmission in Java. These are the following requirements for the client application:

```
1.el host y puerto del servidor (client must choose host and port from server)
2.la velocidad de transmisión en paquetes/seg. (client must choose velocity of packets/sec)
3.el número total de paquetes a enviar o la duración de la transmisión en segundos (choose a total number of packets to send or duration of transimission in seconds)
4.el valor inicial de la secuencia y (initial value of y sequence)
5.el tamaño de la parte de datos de los paquetes. (Los datos específicos no tienen importancia, el cliente puede rellenarlos con cualquier texto, siempre y cuando el número de bytes enviados en cada paquete corresponda a lo que indicó el cliente). (The size of the data portion of the packets, client can fill data with any text it only matters that the sent bytes are the same the client said)
```

I have programmed a client/server application before, where I sent my name and the server sent me back a confirmation number which I sent back to it.

I've checked the presentations (.ppts) and these 5 points to be grade are nowhere to be found...  I ask humbly this community with if not full help of my problem a push in the right direction of where I should find these? My guess is that most of this is already in methods inside java.net.*. I guess #1 must be donde with a first message to the server indicating host and port, which then it creates. Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.DatagramSocket.
java.net.DatagramPacket.
```

Item #1 doesn't make any sense. I suggest you've mistranslated, or misunderstood. My Spanish is strictly Hollywood but it doesn't say anything about choosing that I can see.